# Kubernetes Basic - Cluster IP

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a basic understanding that pods need to be exposed as service. Now I would like to know that
the frontend Pod(like web pods) must be exposed as Load Balancer service and backend pods (like app or DB pods) must be exposed as ClientIP. And there is no configuration from within the application(Java/Python). My question may be silly but I would like to understand.
In a Two-tier or three tier architecture we will be configuring in the application side. Likewise I am trying to understand the concept here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this helps to understand the difference and when to use what [ClusterIp, NodePort, LoadBalancer, and Ingress](https://www.ovh.com/blog/getting-external-traffic-into-kubernetes-clusterip-nodeport-loadbalancer-and-ingress/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To establish the communication between component (frontend, backend and database) I think you need  to make :

- A deployment for each component
- Service type clusterIp to establish communication between backend and database.
- Service type clusterIP to establish communication between backend and frontend.
- To make your application accessible from the outside you can use service type nodePort or load balancer .

To resume:

- Service type clusterIP for inter communication inside cluster.
- Node port to make your service accessible at node level.
  I hope that make this part clear for you .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was my understanding too!. From the application side is there any configuration that needs to be done? For Ex: I am running a Web App(Frontend) to fill a form and submitting the data to a DB(backend). So now Frontend will be Loadbalancer service and DB will be a ClusterIP service(if I am not wrong). Now the ports are open for accepting the requests. so how does the front end knows here is where it needs to update. Do developers specify it during the front end development?

Comment: every time when you have a new release (new docker image will built) so just modify the docker image also you can change parameters to config your app using environment variable or command. environment variable can be stored on a configmap or secret (in case you have sensitive data) .